# how solve merge dex?

Tags: java, android, gradle

i have this error when i try to run my android app

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

i tried to clean project and rebuild project and tried to remove project but the same error don't solve
  gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lef.planeeye"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.0'
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and post the entire Gradle Console output. The source of your problem should be in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start adding multi dex and changing your application to a multidexapplication. Consider minimizing your dependencies to the dependencies you need. You are importing the entire google play services.

Consider only including the ones you need or you will defintely exceed the 65,536 method limitation which will make you compile slower and have to adjust your gradle properties to speed things up with more memory.

If you must do multi-dex then update your application extends MultiDexApplication as well as your gradle properties to increase memory, but hopefully you don't have to do that.

Try to fix the problem properly before you patch it ;).

However, if it is not a multi-dex issue, it could be an issue dexing repeat dependencies of different versions. Possibly your google play service. I would run assembleRelease --info and get more info.

In the meantime, try forcing the play lib version all the way through in your manifest with this exact line

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        tools:replace="android:value" />
```

inside the application tag

Comment: this problem appear when run app on emulator when run on mobile run well ! why ?

Comment: Well you may not have a mutli-dexing issue then. It could be the installed play services version on the emulator. Make sure you force the correct version in the manfiest.

Comment: how check the  play services version ?

Comment: Just copy the snippet I gave you above. It will force the app version as the default version of all. Copy exactly as I posted

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.lef.planeeye, PID: 3807
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.lef.planeeye-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.lef.planeeye-1, /system/lib]]

Comment: Rana that is a different issue then this question. You are not finding your firebase class now. Which means you probably did not configure your firebase wizard setup properly. I'm not going to go into multiple questions on this single question. Start a new question if that is your error on firebase so people who want to help with firebase can help you. If my fix got you past your dex error then please mark my answer as the correct answer. Then post the new question for firebase help and I'll look there to answer that one

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable multidexing

set  `multiDexEnabled true` in your gradl.build file
and add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to your dependencies
Here is an example from my app

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: this problem appear when run app on emulator when run on mobile run well ! why ?

Comment: @RanaTarek just try enabling multidexing in your code you had before any suggested here alterations. And see if it works.

Comment: @RanaTarek if not then it;s not the multidexing problem